# Quaternion problem?

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a problem with this function: geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat= tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

when I give the input value "th" in degree it functions and the robot turns but with bad precision.
And when I give the input in radians it doesn't function at all !!!

I don't know where's the problem !

Any suggestion please !

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233619/quaternion-problem-!?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-05-04**:
You could edit this question to provide a bit more context, otherwise, I'm guessing people will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This function definitely takes its input in radians. I just tested it with a few different yaw angles and the `geometry_msgs::Quaternion` created produced the expected values. I'm guessing the issue lies with your robot, its interfaces, or its controllers.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3